# Center main container for large screens in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am picking up an existing free template Jessicawhite at [html5xcss3.com](http://www.html5xcss3.com/2014/02/jessicawhite-responsive-html5-theme.html)

I notice the images stretch 100% in any screen and in large screen (MAC wide screen for e.g.), it looks really ugly especially the home page slider.

I want to center the whole page/body if the screen is larger than the max size of my images (1280px, sized in the server) like in this site: [igihe.com](http://www.igihe.com) I tried playing with bootstrap-responsive.css. The highest screen it deals with is 1200px min.

```
@media (min-width:  1200px) {

}
```

My attempt was for screens with minimum 1400px:

```
  @media (max-width:  1200px) {
  //leave original intact
   }

   @media (min-width:  1400px) {
   body {width:1366px; margin:0 auto;}
   /* OR */
   .body_container {width:1366px; margin:0 auto;}
   }
```

As well, I just tried changing the min-width:1200px to min-width:1400px but it doesn't behave well either.

My issues are: it doesn't correctly react. My screen size is 1366px, which is less than 1400px yet it applies the body styles.

Need i add all the specs under each media to each screen size after words? Meaning, the min-width:1200px contains a bunch of specs. Does that mean each screen size has to define it?

Any shorter solution that puts the menu in consideration?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the simple css3.
use a wrapper division o wrap all your elements and this wrapper have a display:none; by default for all width of media.

```
.wrapper{
     display:none;
     width:your-width-num px;
     margin-right:auto;
     margin-left:auto;
}
```

And for the wider screens:

```
@meida(min-width:your-width-num) {
     .wrapper{
     display:block;
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks. But wouldn't display:none hide all elements and block under it then? I did set width to 1400px, which is the width I want. But the whole page is now closed for smaller screens.

Comment: so @samsam do not use the width element and also use clear the display prop.